# Variable Containing Reference to a List but When Referenced List Deleted?

Tags: python, python-3.x, reference, del

From what I understand, assigning a list variable to a variable will create a reference like a pointer in C.

```
>>> l1 = ['joe biden', 'donald trump', 'justin trudeau']
>>> l2 = l1
>>> l1
['joe biden', 'donald trump', 'justin trudeau']
>>> l2
['joe biden', 'donald trump', 'justin trudeau']
>>> l1.append('barack obama')
>>> l1
['joe biden', 'donald trump', 'justin trudeau', 'barack obama']
>>> l2
['joe biden', 'donald trump', 'justin trudeau', 'barack obama']
>>>
```

this is expected.

but here is the thing:

```
>>> del l1
>>> l1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'l1' is not defined
>>> l2
['joe biden', 'donald trump', 'justin trudeau', 'barack obama']
>>> l1.append('obama')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'l1' is not defined
>>> l2.append('obama')
>>> l2
['joe biden', 'donald trump', 'justin trudeau', 'barack obama', 'obama']
>>>
```

l1 is deleted, so what is l2 pointing to? It seems l2 contains its own list now. Why does this happen?

Comment: "From what I understand, assigning a list variable to a variable will create a reference like a pointer in C." Assigning *anything* to a variable simply creates a new reference to some object. Python *doesn't have pointers*, but *everything has reference semantics*. The semantics of assignment are always the same, regardless of the types of objects involved. Note, Python is a dynamically typed languages, *variables* don't have types, *objects* have types

Comment: Read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`del` deletes variables, not objects. The variables `l1` and `l2` were "pointing" to (more correct term is "referencing") the same list, you deleted the variable `l1`, and you had the variable `l2` left. An object is deleted only if the garbage collector detects that the object has no references left. A further `del l2` should trigger that.

If Python did allow you to delete an object, you could end up accidentally using still-alive variables or indices to access a deleted object, something like a dangling pointer.

Answer (score 1):

l2 points to the memory location of l1 rather than l1.Hence, if l1 is deleted you still have l2 pointing to the same list

Comment: So what is `del` deleting exactly? [The del keyword is used to delete objects](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_del.asp). Or is it not really **deleting** anything?

Comment: the object will be deleted when there are no more references to it. l2 still references the list.

Comment: @poweredbycocaine it's deleting the reference (pointer), not the object.  The object doesn't get deleted until ALL the references to it are deleted.

Comment: @MarkRansom right,,, ok. Makes much sense. How can I delete something in memory?

Comment: @poweredbycocaine **no** the `del` keyword **does not delete objects**. Python provides *no control* over memory management. `del x` deletes *a variable from a namespace*, that is all. Once all references to an object are gone, it is free to be garbage collected. CPython, which uses reference counting as it's main memory management strategy, will reclaim objects as soon as a reference count reaches zero, but that is an implementationd etail

Comment: @poweredbycocaine the only way is to delete all the references, as I said.  As long as there's a single reference the object will still exist.

Comment: @poweredbycocaine you can't. Stop thinking int terms of "pointers" and "deleting things from memory". Python is a high level language. Think in terms of *objects* and *names/references* to objects.

Comment: @poweredbycocaine the max you can do is clear the list using l1.clear() this removes all the elements from both the lists

Comment: @Kritarth that really has nothing to do with deleting things from memory. It's very important to understand, *Python doesn't give you control over memory management*.

Comment: @poweredbycocaine as an aside, that is one of many great examples of why you should simply never trust anything written in w3schools. It's a *terrible* resource, which frequently just has outright wrong information about even the most basic things. Just don't use it. Use the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga okay thanks for the correction:)